# Parsing external passwd and shadow file automatically?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, passwords

I want to parse a copy of the passwd and shadow files from another computer in C. I know that I can parse the passwd and shadow files on the local computer using:

```
struct passwd *getpwent(void);
struct spwd *getspent(void);
```

But this does not take a file as input argument, so I was wondering if there is an equivalent function that takes the passwd and shadow file as input argument.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [struct passwd *fgetpwent(FILE *stream)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetpwent.3.html)

Works exactly the same but takes a "FILE *" as argument.